# filtering data by API calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-table

I have a table on my page and custom filters for this table, so by default I'm using API call that to load data.

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
 url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events/'
 });
```

On the left side I have filters. This filters I'm getting thru http get method

```
$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/EventTypeCategories"
        }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
        }, function error(response) {
            $scope.categories = response.statusText;
        });
```

and rendering filters thru scope function

```
$scope.selectCat = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category) {
                if (category.selected) {

                    $scope.selectedAllCat = false;

                    if (category.name == "Study") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=1'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (category.name == "Corporate") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=2'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (category.name == "Safety") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=3'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (category.name == "Partners") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=4'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (category.name == "Standards") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=5'
                        });
                    }
                    else if (category.name == "Technology") {
                        $scope.checked = true;
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                            url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=6'
                        });
                    }
                }

            });
        };
```

html

```
  <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllCat" ng-click="selectAllCat()">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="col-md-9">All</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {{ categories.length }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy : 'id' ">
                                <td class="col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category.selected" ng-click="selectCat()">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="col-md-9">{{ category.name }}</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {{ category.selected }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

      <table id="table"
                           data-flat="true"
                           data-toggle="table"
                           data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                           data-search="true"
                           data-show-toggle="false"
                           data-show-columns="true"
                           data-show-export="true"
                           data-filter-control="true"
                           data-events="operateEvents"
                           data-formatter="operateFormatter"
                           data-response-handler="responseHandler"
                           class="table-striped">
                    </table>
```

My question is what do I have to do for multiple category selections?

Comment: You mean this? `'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category[]=4&category[]=5&category[]=6'` ?

Comment: I mean if user selects for example categories 1 and 3, it should show him both selected categories, but now It shows only last selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: With more explanation.**
Your goal here would be to compose the **query string** to be able to filter upon multiple categories.

When you want category 1, you do a request like:
*http://address:8080/events-api/rest/Events?**category=1***

Now, you want to filter upon category 1 and 6 with a single request, so your request should be like this:

*http://address:8080/events-api/rest/Events?**category=1&category=6***

So, in your code you should:
**1** Change the markup from:

`<td class="col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category.selected" ng-click="selectCat()">&nbsp;</td>`
to:
`<td class="col-md-1"> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="updateFilter(category.id)">&nbsp;</td>`

**2** The following function will help us to keep track of currently marked filters:

```
 $scope.selectedFilters = [];
    $scope.updateFilter = function(categoryId) {

        if ($scope.selectedFilters.indexOf(categoryId) > -1) {
            $scope.selectedFilters.push(categoryId);
        } else {
        $scope.selectedFilters.splice($scope.selectedFilters.indexOf(categoryId), 1);
    }

    //Optional, to reload on change.
    $scope.requestEvents();
}
```

**3**: The following function to request data, based on selected filters, will work also without filters at all.

```
$scope.requestEvents() {
    var url = 'http://address:8080/events-api/rest/Events';

    if ($scope.selectedFilters.length > -1) {
        var queryString = '?category=';
        queryString += $scope.selectedFilters.join('&category=');
        url += queryString;
    }
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
        'url': url
    });
}
```

-- Old version --
Not sure if this will be clear from the first time, but it's due to lack of details from your side. So, keeping the code style as you already have it, you can write something like this.

```
$scope.filterByCategory = function(categories) {
    //Assuming you have in categories, an array of numbers, (or 
    //strings, anyway they should match categories from your backend)
    categories = categories.join('&category=');
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
        url: 'http://address:8080/events-api/rest/Events?category=6' + categories
}
```

Note, depending on your backend, query string maybe should be joined by ('&category[]='), instead of ('&category=')

Comment: you are right it is not clear from the first time. What's kind of info you'd like to get more?  I'm trying to make a plunker for you

Comment: well, I have a problem with `Mixed Content` and can't provide an example... if I right got you, so my scope var should look like `angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category) {
                    category = category.join('&category=');
                    if (category.selected) {
                        if (category.name == "Study") {
                            $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                                url: 'http://address:8080/events-api1/rest/Events?category=1' + category
                            });
                        }` right?

Comment: No, your scope var should not be like this.
If you could provide a plunkr, it would be nice.

Or if not, i'll do one tomorrow for you.

Comment: The problem in plunker is that my api provides http but plunker works with only https calls, that's why I can't provide example in plunker

Comment: So could you help me with my issue?

Comment: Wow, it is really great answer, only two things: First, I would appreciate if you provide some links where could I learn it more deep and the second one currently I'm trying to debug your code, because for some reason I'm getting this error ` Cannot read property 'index' of undefined`..

Comment: Define in the beginning of your controller
`$scope.selectedFilters = []`
and recheck if you didn't misspell **indexOf**.

Actually you can google keywords from my answer to get more information. Or  tell me what sequence of my answer seems unclear, so i'll improve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111795/discussion-between-anton-and-stefan-hariton).